# Dealing with a union type where one of two functions can provide the value

Tags: typescript

I have two methods that are very similar and I want to DRY up the repeated code. The separate functions are:

```
//returns a single element
const getByDataTest = (
  container: HTMLElement,
  dataTest: string
) => {
  const element = queryByAttribute(
    'data-test',
    container,
    dataTest
  );

  if (!element) {
    throw queryHelpers.getElementError(
      `Unable to find element by: [data-test="${dataTest}"]`,
      container
    );
  }
  return element;
};

//returns multiple elements
const getAllByDataTest = (
  container: HTMLElement,
  dataTest: string
) => {
  const elements = queryAllByAttribute(
    'data-test',
    container,
    dataTest
  );

  if (elements.length === 0) {
    throw queryHelpers.getElementError(
      `Unable to find any elements by: [data-test="${dataTest}"]`,
      container
    );
  }
  return elements;
};
```

What I'm trying to do is merge these into one function that takes a `multiple` argument and uses either one query method or the other:

```
const getDataTest = (
  container: HTMLElement,
  dataTest: string,
  multiple = false
) => {
  //choose which query method to use
  const queryMethod = multiple ? queryHelpers.queryAllByAttribute : queryHelpers.queryByAttribute;
  const result = queryMethod(
    'data-test',
    container,
    dataTest
  );

  if ((multiple && result.length === 0) || !result) {
    throw queryHelpers.getElementError(
      `Unable to find any element by: [data-test="${dataTest}"]`,
      container
    );
  }
  return result;
};
```

Because `result` is `HTMLElement | HTMLElement[]`, the `result.length` complains. I have tried to extend the condition to `if ((multiple && result.length && result.length === 0)` but it still complains at the first instance of `result.length`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WzLG1N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  You should probably *remove* code instead of *adding* it.  If your problem is that you cannot index into an `HTMLElement | HTMLElement[]`, then you can demonstrate that in two lines of code [like this](//tsplay.dev/wQe2nw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not let you index into a value of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with a key if that key does not exist on all members of the union:

```
let result: HTMLElement | HTMLElement[];
result = Math.random() < 0.5 ? document.body : [document.body];

result.length // sad
```

The reason for that is that object types are open/extendible, so nothing prevents an `HTMLElement` from having a `length` property of some unknown value type:

```
const possibleResult = Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), { length: "whaaa" });
result = possibleResult; // <-- this is fine

console.log(possibleResult.length) // "whaaa", not a number
```

So technically you cannot assume that there is a `length` property and that if there is one it will be a `number` or if it is a `number` that you've got an array instead of a weird `HTMLElement`-with-extra-`length` property.

---

The "right" way to do this in TypeScript is to use a *type guard* to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) `result` to either `HTMLElement` or `HTMLElement[]`.  TypeScript lets you use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) as such a type guard, so the fix could be like this:

```
if (Array.isArray(result)) {
  result.map(x => x.tagName) // happy
} else {
  result.tagName // also happy
}
```

Another thing you could do is use the [`in` operator as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing):

```
if ("length" in result) {
  result.map(x => x.tagName) // still happy
} else {
  result.tagName // ditto
}
```

TypeScript uses `"length" in result` to filter the type of `result` to those union elements with or without a known `length` property.  This is very convenient... but has exactly the same problem that `result.length` with no check has: it is of course possible that `"length" in result` returns `true` without `result` being an array at all.  So the `in` operator allows [unsound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) things to happen.  But this is intentional, (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39065#issuecomment-643826453) on [microsoft/TypeScript#39065](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39065)); the TypeScript team thinks that someone writing `result.length` might not necessarily be trying to discriminate a union based on this, while someone writing `"length" in result` is definitely trying to do so and so the language should let them.  There is at least one feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#45211](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45211) saying that instead of just yelling at you for writing `result.length`, the compiler should maybe say "if you're trying to narrow `result` based on the presence of the `length` property, try `"length" in result`".

---

There are other ways to narrow unions, but one of those should work for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAGwpgLgBATmDOBXEEBcUASAVAsgGQFFwBbMAO2gB9NdCTyIBtAXQG5gOBjAezPmgAO3ePACWAI3AAlBMmgBeKAHlxAKzCcIAOgCGI0QHMyACgAm3TolIUtnODohgiYaxGMAiU6IBu7gJQANFAA3lDgZAYQABbo7gDuUTpJ7lAAvn7sPHzc4Fog3AbGQvqSYDJIKHnkkVF+UAD09VDxiclBZNzQOlBkVuJgMMBwFQpQxWKl5XLsQ7IoUIo4DlFaMDpk5sTGdQA8UAAMWgCsUAD8UOaWrlri3KYAnlDojJdWDDd392wcw3JVEdEGk14DpTBxgKIAGZQYwAQRga3uWlE8HhiOMvxQfjqwWAUFgc20xB0AmMAA8FgA+KBkrQQHQGAByOlIdUaUESAgE92AqSgYBA8DAITxBJGdIZzNIQKgOkF3A5JO5vI4UJh7nCNRSojIYrkONFmKJJPJVJpEqZLLAbOBEFEIBAiq5PL5AqFIvxRotUuF7K8EAg3F5QA)